# Implementing a trait method returning a bounded lifetime reference for owned type

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, borrowing

Let's assume I have this struct and this trait:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct New<T>(T);

pub trait AsRefNew<'a> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> New<&'a str>;
}
```

That is, the `AsRefNew` trait allows to return a reference with a given lifetime `'a` wrapped in a `New` newtype. This lifetime `'a` may be different (and will be) from the lifetime of the `&self` parameter.

Now I can implement this trait for a `New(&str)`, and make it so that the lifetime of the output is the lifetime of the wrapped `&str`:

```rust
impl<'a> AsRefNew<'a> for New<&'a str> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> New<&'a str>{
        New(self.0)
    }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to implement the trait for `New(String)`, and this time, I would like `'a` to actually match the lifetime of `self`. My understanding is that something like that should work:

```rust
impl<'a> AsRefNew<'a> for New<String> where Self: 'a{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> New<&'a str> {
        New(self.0.as_str())
    }
}
```

Except it does not:

```rust
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:16:20
   |
16 |         New(self.0.as_str())
   |                    ^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 15:5...
  --> src/main.rs:15:5
   |
15 |     fn as_ref(&self) -> New<&'a str> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
16 |         New(self.0.as_str())
   |             ^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 14:6...
  --> src/main.rs:14:6
   |
14 | impl<'a> AsRefNew<'a> for New<String> where Self: 'a{
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         New(self.0.as_str())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `New<&'a str>`
              found `New<&str>`
```

I tried different variations of lifetimes and generic, but I can not find a better way to express the fact that I, in this case, want `'a` to match `'_`.

The goal is to have this snippet to work:

```rust
fn main() {
    // This works:
    let a = String::from("Hey");
    let b;
    {
        let c = New(a.as_str());
        b = c.as_ref().0;
    }
    println!("{:?}", b);
    
    // I would like that to work as well:
    let a = String::from("Ho");
    let b;
    let c = New(a);
    {
        b = c.as_ref().0;
    }
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is answerable until you elaborate on "This lifetime `'a` may be different (and will be) from the lifetime of the `&self` parameter" with some concrete examples. Please edit your question to update it with additional clarifying details. Given your question as-is I was [able to come up with this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4c9be6ec816a90692848bc3281889757) but I'm not sure if it actually solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for having a look ! I added an example to show what I would like to have ! So I really neeed the implementation for `New<String>`, and not for `New<&String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Sven, in order to make that work, we would need two different method prototypes, and that is not possible with the `AsRefNew` trait as it is defined.

Still, it can be modified to make the small snippet work by, e.g. introducing a second lifetime in the signature:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct New<T>(T);

pub trait AsRefNew<'b, 'a> {
    fn as_ref(&'b self) -> New<&'a str>;
}

impl<'a> AsRefNew<'_, 'a> for New<&'a str> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> New<&'a str>{
        New(self.0)
    }
}

impl<'b, 'a> AsRefNew<'b, 'a> for New<String> where 'b:'a {
    fn as_ref(&'b self) -> New<&'a str> {
        New(self.0.as_str())
    }
}

impl<T> New<T> {
    pub fn test<'b, 'a>(&'b self) -> New<&'a str> where Self: AsRefNew<'b, 'a> {
        self.as_ref()
    }
}
```

The following snippet now works:

```rust
fn main() {
    // This works:
    let a = String::from("Hey");
    let b;
    {
        let c = New(a.as_str());
        b = c.as_ref().0;
    }
    println!("{:?}", b);
    
    // It now works
    let a = String::from("Ho");
    let b;
    let c = New(a);
    {
        b = c.as_ref().0;
    }
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

And so is this generic implementation of a method on the `New` type:

```rust
impl<T> New<T> {
    pub fn test<'b, 'a>(&'b self) -> New<&'a str> where Self: AsRefNew<'b, 'a> {
        self.as_ref()
    }
}
```

The only problem now is that the signature is super ugly! I wonder whether this could made simpler with gats.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible. Trait methods can only have a single prototype, and all implementations have to match that prototype.

For the case `New<&'a str>`, your prototype needs to be what you have

```
fn as_ref(&self) -> New<&'a str>;
```

For the case `New<String>`, on the other hand, you would need

```
fn as_ref<'b>(&'b self) -> New<&'b str>;
```

instead, i.e. the lifetime of the return value needs to be tied to the lifetime of the `self` reference. This prototype is different, since lifetimes are part of the prototype.

Your attempt to solve this with a trait bound `Self: 'a` can't work. The type `Self` is `New<String>` here, which does not contain any references, so it in fact trivially fulfils `Self: 'static`, and thus any lifetime bound. The bound does not further constrain the `Self` type in any way. You can't restrict the lifetime of the `self` reference at the impl level, and bounding it at the function definition level will result in diverging from the prototype in the trait definition, as explained above.

For the same reason, you can't get an `&'a str` from a `Cow<'a, str>` by dereferencing. The `Cow` might be owned, in which case the returned reference can only live as long a the `self` reference used for dereferencing.

Comment: That is so sad ! Yeah, I thought that adding the bound could somehow hint the compiler into understanding that `&self` is really `&'a self`, but it is definitely not working. Any other ideas about how to make my snippet work ? I could not find any other solution, but there may be one!

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to make that work. At the place where you use the trait, e.g. in generic code with a `T: AsRefNew<'a>`, the compiler needs to be able to determine the lifetime of the reference returned by `as_ref()` without knowing the actual type of `T`, since otherwise it would be impossible to borrow-check the generic code.

Comment: Yes, and that is precisely what I wanted to achieve with the trait. But thanks to your remark, I now understand that I wanted the method prototype to somehow change between the implementations, but this is not possible indeed.

Comment: Just found a way to make it work by modifying the signature, but it is now super ugly. Thanks for your feedback though ;)